# How to explicit loading long navigation properties' chain using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I have this code to explicit loading for an entity:

```
dbContext.StorageRequests.Add(storageRequest);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
//Here I want to explict loading some navigation properties
dbContext.Entry(storageRequest).Reference(c => c.Manager).Load();
dbContext.Entry(storageRequest).Reference(c => c.Facility).Load();
dbContext.Entry(storageRequest).Collection(x=> x.PhysicalObjects).Query().Include(x => x.Classification).Load();
```

My question is two parts:

The first one how can I load all together (I want to call Load() once)?

The second part does the above code sends query for each Load() calling which in turn hit the database to load related data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar question withEF core. Turning on SQL logging to the debugoutput window helped answer a lot of my questions as to what it was doing, and why. In terms of your questions:

1) You can't, though you can eager load it with a series of `dbContext.Collection.Include(otherCollection).ThenInclude(stuffRelatedToOtherCollection)` type chains

2) Yes it does, even eager loading in one c# statement bangs out multiple queries. I presumed this was because it's too much of a complex artificial intelligence problem to do it any way other than its most naive multiple-sql, because it's hard for the framework to deal with cartesian products when multiple tables are joined together in one rectangular dataset. (A school has students and teachers, teacher:students is a many:many relationship, decomposed by class. If you wrote one query to join school, class, student and teachers, you'd get repeated data all over the place and though conceptually possible to pick through it looking for unique school, class teacher and student primary key values, you could be downloading tens of thousands of duplicated rows only to have to unique them all again. EF tends to select the school ,then school join class, then school join class join students, then school join class join teachers (if that's how you coded your school include class theninclude students then include teachers. Changing your include strategy will change the queries that are run)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I meant by performance sending multiple request to database through the wire not sending multiple queries within the same request.So I think that chained include will hit the database once !

Comment: For performance concerns of that ilk, you'd be better off adopting a caching strategy with something like a local redis, if your database is in some remote datacentre. Your database reader tries the cache, if it misses it fills the cache from the db. Your database writer invalidates the cache (it doesnt need to re fill it, the reader will do that next time it's called upon)

Answer (score 2):

Nice question! Let me answer differently, in reverse order, with new info.

### 2.)

Each `Load()` will cause a query to the database as of the documentation ([Querying and Finding Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/) - 10/23/2016):

> A query is executed against the database when:
>
> - It is enumerated by a **foreach** (C#) or **For Each** (Visual Basic) statement.
> - It is enumerated by a collection operation such as [ToArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb298736), [ToDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary), or [ToList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb342261).
> - LINQ operators such as [First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb291976) or [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb337697) are specified in the outermost part of the query.
> - The following methods are called: the [Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.entity.dbextensions.load) extension method on a DbSet, [DbEntityEntry.Reload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry.reload.aspx), and [Database.ExecuteSqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand?view=entity-framework-6.2.0).

---

People often uses [eager loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/) with `Include()` to let EF optimize as much as possible:

> in most cases, EF will combine the joins when generating SQL

```
// ef 6
using System.Data.Entity;

var storageRequests = dbContext.StorageRequests
    .Include(r => r.PhysicalObjects.Select(p => p.Classification))
    .Include(r => r.Manager)
    .Include(r => r.Facility);

// evaluate "storageRequests" here by linq method or foreach
```

or:

```
// ef core
var storageRequests = dbContext.StorageRequests
    .Include(r => r.PhysicalObjects)
    .ThenInclude(p => p.Classification)
    .Include(r => r.Manager)
    .Include(r => r.Facility);

// evaluate "storageRequests" here by linq method or foreach
```

---

### 1.)

Only possible way I can imagine is having above code with `storageRequests.Load()`.
You could inspect whether it:

- generates single/multiple queries,
- loads navigation property data along `StorageRequest`.

FYI: these query executions are also called ***network roundtrips*** in microsoft docs:

> Multiple network roundtrips can degrade performance, especially where latency to the database is high (for example, cloud services).

---

### Point of interest:

There is a relative new option [Single vs. Split Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries) (10/03/2019) in .Net Core 5.

The default is ***single queries*** (behavior described above). After that you can decide to request/load data per table instead, by adding `.AsSplitQuery()` to your linq query, before the evaluation. Splitted queries increases roundtrips and memory usage (does not loads distinct data) but helps performance.

There is also `.AsSingleQuery()` if [your global choice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries#enabling-split-queries-globally) was:

```
.UseSqlServer(
    connectionString,
    o => o.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery));
```